# Windows 7 dos batch file to open file read second or third line and rename file to found text

Tags: windows-7, batch, rename

I have about two thousand text files I need to rename, but I need to open the file find the line starting with the letter "O", extract the "O" and the next five characters, close the file, then rename the file to the found text.

I've been messing around with it for a couple of says trying to teach myself enough about doing this to try, but I'm running out of time.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Otherwise I'll have to open each file, find the text and rename the files one at a time.

**EDIT**
First off. thanks for the replies.

There is only one line per text file beginning with the "O". These are CNC programs and the "O" is the program name that the CNC equipment recognizes. For example "O01234".

This is an example of the format of the program.

```
%

O01234
```

Sometimes the first line of the file is empty or just a CR, and the next line would contain the %. Thats why I said the second or third line would contain the "O". Currently the programs have an alpha-numeric file name like "V180OP20.ptp" The file extension .ptp is just what our CAM software attaches. The files themselves contain nothing but ASCII text.

It is also possible that some of the files will contain only four numbers after the "O" instead of five.

Comment: Welcome to SU! We are not a script writing service. If you have a script you're working on we can help, but you'll need to supply what you've got already, what you've tried, and where exactly you're getting stuck implementing the batch script you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FOR loop with findstr to find the lines beginning with "O" and then rename the files based on the text returned.

Using a few files as an example:

```
C:\temp>dir /s /b
C:\temp\1.txt
C:\temp\2.txt
C:\temp\3.txt
```

You can use the following command to return the text for lines beginning with "O" for all files in the current directory and any subdirectories:

```
C:\temp>findstr /S /B O *.txt
1.txt:Oabcde
2.txt:Oabcdf
3.txt:Oabcdg
```

You can now use the colon from the output as a delimiter to separate current file names from the desired ones:

```
C:\temp>for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %A in ('findstr /S /B O *.txt') do ren %A %B.txt
C:\temp>ren 1.txt Oabcde.txt
C:\temp>ren 2.txt Oabcdf.txt
C:\temp>ren 3.txt Oabcdg.txt
```

You don't list many details, so it's impossible to give the exact command you need, but hopefully this example gets you started. You can use regular expressions with findstr if the O and the following five characters are not the only characters on that line.

**EDIT** :: Based on the update/edit from the OP, CD to the directory with your files and run the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %A in ('findstr /S /B O *.ptp') do ren %A %B.ptp
```

Comment: Good idea, However, what if there are multiple lines that begin with "O"?

Comment: In that case we have to use a regex to find the line we care about. For example, if the lines we care about start with "O" followed by numbers, then change the command to use: 'findstr /S /RC:"^O[0-9]" *.txt'

Comment: Yes, the OP did not really provide enough detail. But based on title statement that it should be 2nd or 3rd line, I suspect the OP wants the first line starting with O.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 features a new shell much better than DOS, it is called PowerShell.
PowerShell can be opened with the "Start Menu > All Programs > Administrative Tools > Windows PowerShell" shortcut.

You will need to run this command once to enable scripts to run on your computer:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then you just have to create the script (.ps1 file extension) with the following code lines:

```
$myFolderFullOfTextFiles = 'C:\Temp\Test'
$linesToReadInEachTextFile = 5

$myTextFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $myFolderFullOfTextFiles

foreach( $textFile in $myTextFiles )
{
    $newName = ''

    foreach( $line in $(Get-Content -Path $textFile.FullName -Head $linesToReadInEachTextFile) )
    {
        if( $line -like 'O*' )
        {
           $newName = $textFile.DirectoryName + '\' + $line.Substring(0,6) + '.txt'
        }
    }

    try
    {
        Write-Host $newName
        Rename-Item -Path $textFile.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Failed to rename $textFile."
    }
}
```

Replace `'C:\Temp\Test'` by your folder path, and remove `+ '.txt'` if your text files have no extensions.
Then just run the script.